# Change Selected Index of Tab Bar Application from Modal View Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, modal-dialog

I'm creating a tab bar application using the built-in tab bar app template in Xcode. I have 4 tabs, one of which is a mapView. For a few of the view controllers my code programmatically sets the selected index of the tab bar depending on the user actions. For the mapView view controller I have a method that presents a modal view when the user taps on a selected annotation. The modal view has some information about that selected annotation. I can dismiss the modal view controller and return to the mapView correctly.

My problem is that I would like to put a 'home' button on the modal view controller that should dismiss the modal view *and* take the user to 0 index on the tab bar (AKA home). The mapView is index 3.

I cannot do a [self.tab setSelectedIndex:0] from the modal view attached to the home button - it doesn't work. Perhaps I'm overthinking this. Can anyone offer a solution / hint? I greatly appreciate it! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you present a modal view controller from one of the tabs, the tab bar controller instance becomes the `parentViewController` of the modal view controller. You can use this property to call the tab bar controller methods.

```
[(UITabBarController *)self.parentViewController setSelectedIndex:0];
```